# What happens on the backend when you enter and save a value in a SharePointWebControl:UserField?

Tags: 2010

**I have:** A page layout with a `SharePointWebControl:UserField` which collects username in each page that the page layout is applied to.

**I am trying to accomplish:** Get the value saved in the UserField from each page in the site collection.

**My approach:**
Option 1: Get the rendered HTML of each page and navigate the DOM to get the value.
Option 2: Query the backend storage where the `UserField` value is stored, based on page URL.

I believe Option 2 is the way to go. I, however, do not know the mechanics of how SharePoint saves the information in the back end. This is where I need your help. Could someone please suggest what happens in the backend when I enter a value into the `UserField` and save?

**UPDATE**

Here is what I am trying to achieve: To get the value that is displayed on each page of a given site collection. For eg. lets say, my company has many departments. Each department gets its own site and on the site's default page, we have a field that displays the department head's name. I would like to go through all the pages in the company and get a list of department heads by reading it off of the user field in the default page. I am using page layout to place the control on the page. Please let me know if I am not being clear with what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: User Field is actually a lookup column to one of the Hidden lists named "User Information List".. So you can read it just like a lookup column, meaning load the `SPFieldLookupValue` object and than properties like `LookupValue` and `LookupId` help

Comment: Than you for your feedback. How do I use this information to query each page in a site collection to get the value, without having to render the page?

Comment: You can loop through all the items in Pages Library and read for your desired Person field.. Can you tell me what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Please see above. I have updated the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tom,

You will need to iterate through the SPWebs in SPSite object and get the welcome page, than access the Department Head property..

A pseudo-code can look like:

```
SPSite site = new SPSite("http://siteurl");
foreach (SPWeb web in site.AllWebs)
{
    SPListItem welcomePage = web.GetFile(web.RootFolder.WelcomePage).Item;
    if (welcomePage["DepartmentHead"] != null)
    {
        SPFieldUserValue userValue = new SPFieldUserValue(web, welcomePage["DepartmentHead"].ToString());
        SPUser deptHead = userValue.User;

        // do something with this user
    }
}
```

Of course you will need to dispose the objects or enclose them in using..

Comment: This actually works. I didn't know that the fields rendered on the page show up as page properties - or perhaps, vice versa. I will have to confirm that only the fields in the content type associated with the page can be dropped on the page itself. Otherwise, this is just a pure co-incidence! How does it work at the page layout level?

Comment: Page Layout is a blueprint just like a class in C#. It exists when you create a Page based on the Page Layout..

Comment: A page is infact nothing but a List Item of a Pages List.. So you can access all its properties as Fields !

Answer (score 0):

In the code behind of your layout page, you can access to the control (UserField) and use the methode : **[myUserField].value** witch return an object of type SPFieldUserValue

msdn link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.userfield.value(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. But, I don't believe having access to the field value in the backend of the code helps me in this situation.